# how to array tracks to playlist in PHP from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i have a music sharing script and i am trying to create JSON from my mysql database, I'm trying to create a specific structure and can't seem to figure it out

heres my code

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","UN","PW");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("DB",$db);




    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username ASC"); 
    $json_response = array(); //Create an array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array['idu'] = $row['idu'];
        $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
        $row_array['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $row_array['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
        $row_array['country'] = $row['country'];
        $row_array['image'] = $row['image'];
        $row_array['cover'] = $row['cover'];
        $row_array['description'] = $row['description'];
        $row_array['playlists'] = array();  
        $row_array['tracks'] = array();  
        $plid = $row['idu'];

        $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlists where playlists.by=$plid");
        while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
        {
            $row_array['playlists'][] = array(
                'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
                'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
                'by' => $opt_fet['by'],
            );


        }
        array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array


        //tracks


        $option_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks where tracks.uid=$plid");
        while ($opt_fet = mysql_fetch_array($option_qry))
        {
            $row_array['tracks'][] = array(
                'id' => $opt_fet['id'],
                'title' => $opt_fet['title'],
                'name' => $opt_fet['name'],
                'art' => $opt_fet['art'],
                'likes' => $opt_fet['likes'],
                'downloads' => $opt_fet['downloads'],
                'plays' => $opt_fet['views'],
                'uid' => $opt_fet['uid'],



            );


        }
        array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array

    }
    echo json_encode($json_response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

users Table:

```
id  username   last_name  first_name  country etc...
1   username1  Mynce      George      USA     etc...
2   username2  Jenkins    Fred        USA     etc...
3   username3  Walberg    Mark        USA     etc...
4   username4  Smith      Will        USA     etc...
```

playlists Table:

```
id   by  name
1    4   My playlists
2    3   Popular Songs
```

**playlistentries Table:**

```
id  playlists   track
12  1           13
13  1           23
14  1           3
15  1           17
16  1           9
12  2           14
13  2           24
14  2           4
15  2           18
16  2           10
```

tracks Table:

```
id  title      name      art      likes  downloads  views
1   song_title song1.mp3 art1.png 13     8          55
2   song_title song2.mp3 art2.png 12     10         31
3   song_title song3.mp3 art3.png 7      32         50
4   song_title song4.mp3 art4.png 22     11         1
5   song_title song5.mp3 art5.png 1      28         2
```

**The JSON below is the structure i am trying to get, i want each playlist a user creates to nest the tracks associated with that playlist in a nested array under that playlists User>Playlists>Tracks** (user>playlist1>t1,t2,t3,etc... & user>playlist2>t1,t2,t3,etc...), (T for Track fyi)

*I typed out two playlists here "We Give You Praise" and "We Give You Praise 2" for example*

**Question is this:** how do i use **PLAYLISTENTRIES** to array/nest the tracks in a playlists?, I've already nested PLAYLISTS under USERS but i dont know how to go one level deeper with the TRACKS inside the PLAYLISTS itself

```
    {
        "idu": "2",
        "username": "chicagochurch",
        "first_name": "Chicago Christian Center",
        "last_name": "",
        "country": "United States",
        "image": "839674815_146358938_1746691162.png",
        "cover": "173157219_1187606488_302826016.jpg",
        "description": "This is the official Chicago Church Music page.",
        "playlists": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "We Give You Praise",
                "by": "2",
                "tracks": [
                    {
                        "id": "29",
                        "title": "01 We Give You Praise",
                        "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
                        "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "4",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "30",
                        "title": "02 Luvudees",
                        "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
                        "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "3",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "31",
                        "title": "03 Mugo Del",
                        "name": "1366849477_130736941_1367659635.mp3",
                        "art": "1181156184_556035815_1698596436.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "32",
                        "title": "04 San Amensa",
                        "name": "40925819_971317614_1732715256.mp3",
                        "art": "837149755_251638008_1945445596.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "1",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "33",
                        "title": "05 One True God",
                        "name": "1201163785_1107025307_1077346045.mp3",
                        "art": "713651840_1636034922_1247445482.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "34",
                        "title": "06 Mugo Anav",
                        "name": "173569477_686122962_117960391.mp3",
                        "art": "1432749408_578109445_1094716795.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "35",
                        "title": "07 Hallelujah",
                        "name": "133051077_70993845_552471086.mp3",
                        "art": "2040610215_1811023913_383444282.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "36",
                        "title": "08 Sheppard",
                        "name": "984429058_1532916377_1375134853.mp3",
                        "art": "1153269141_143559426_997684622.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "37",
                        "title": "09 I Love you Lord",
                        "name": "794115968_1411878888_673035094.mp3",
                        "art": "1692460167_1433248811_682631716.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "38",
                        "title": "10 Jesus In The Center",
                        "name": "202390322_461558278_1271927584.mp3",
                        "art": "1048499380_362527600_4599069.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "39",
                        "title": "11 Mugo Luvudeemos",
                        "name": "274506373_302381815_356651583.mp3",
                        "art": "1229728795_739090349_686501748.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "40",
                        "title": "12 Onday Chedo Kud",
                        "name": "378498031_1470949688_1199351944.mp3",
                        "art": "308978665_1074723934_419931699.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "41",
                        "title": "13 The Word",
                        "name": "956461611_287666310_43661088.mp3",
                        "art": "1584112229_240532531_977129308.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "4",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
{
                "id": "5",
                "name": "We Give You Praise 2",
                "by": "2",
                "tracks": [
                    {
                        "id": "29",
                        "title": "01 We Give You Praise 2",
                        "name": "1667450919_35711384_1898671201.mp3",
                        "art": "97020012_1272964020_1490042512.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "4",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "30",
                        "title": "02 Luvudees 2",
                        "name": "1361859314_884859216_209326964.mp3",
                        "art": "1591964284_1156840179_1721104535.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "3",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "31",
                        "title": "03 Mugo Del 2",
                        "name": "1366849477_130736941_1367659635.mp3",
                        "art": "1181156184_556035815_1698596436.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "32",
                        "title": "04 San Amensa 2",
                        "name": "40925819_971317614_1732715256.mp3",
                        "art": "837149755_251638008_1945445596.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "1",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "33",
                        "title": "05 One True God",
                        "name": "1201163785_1107025307_1077346045.mp3",
                        "art": "713651840_1636034922_1247445482.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "34",
                        "title": "06 Mugo Anav 2",
                        "name": "173569477_686122962_117960391.mp3",
                        "art": "1432749408_578109445_1094716795.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "35",
                        "title": "07 Hallelujah 2",
                        "name": "133051077_70993845_552471086.mp3",
                        "art": "2040610215_1811023913_383444282.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "36",
                        "title": "08 Sheppard 2",
                        "name": "984429058_1532916377_1375134853.mp3",
                        "art": "1153269141_143559426_997684622.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "37",
                        "title": "09 I Love you Lord 2",
                        "name": "794115968_1411878888_673035094.mp3",
                        "art": "1692460167_1433248811_682631716.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "38",
                        "title": "10 Jesus In The Center 2",
                        "name": "202390322_461558278_1271927584.mp3",
                        "art": "1048499380_362527600_4599069.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "39",
                        "title": "11 Mugo Luvudeemos 2",
                        "name": "274506373_302381815_356651583.mp3",
                        "art": "1229728795_739090349_686501748.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "1",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "40",
                        "title": "12 Onday Chedo Kud 2",
                        "name": "378498031_1470949688_1199351944.mp3",
                        "art": "308978665_1074723934_419931699.png",
                        "likes": "0",
                        "downloads": "0",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "41",
                        "title": "13 The Word 2",
                        "name": "956461611_287666310_43661088.mp3",
                        "art": "1584112229_240532531_977129308.png",
                        "likes": "1",
                        "downloads": "4",
                        "plays": "0",
                        "uid": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

as you can see in the above structure, the playlists is listing the tracks associated with it in its own nested array, I'm sure the playlistentries table will need to be used for this but I dont know how to implement it, Sorry for all the code... but thanks for your help!

**IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO THIS** with the table "playlistsentries"

playlists 1 (and list the name and info of the playlists) has track 1,2,3,4,5,etc.. and list the info for each track? and make the data structure I'm trying to achieve?

because the playlistentries seems to be the table that will make the connection between playlists and tracks...

I'm completely lost on what to do... thanks for any help

Comment: just build a php structure to your satisfaction. json encoding is the **LAST** and **EASIEST**  thing in all of this.

Comment: @MarcB i purchased this script from codecanyon and its a very complex structure, and to change it i would have to change would be a big hassle to  change a lot of things that are already using the current structure, thats why I'm trying to figure this out

Answer (score 2):

It all starts wirh your query.  Pretty much any time you see yourself running nested queries like that, you should rethink your approach.  I would suggest querying all your data in a single query using joins, and then reading that result set out into a data structure that you can easily serialize to JSON.

Here is the query I would use:

```
SELECT
  u.`idu` AS `user_id`,
  u.`username` AS `user_name`,
  u.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
  u.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
  u.`country` AS `user_country`,
  u.`image` AS `user_image`,
  u.`cover` AS `user_cover`,
  u.`description` AS `user_description`,
  pl.`id` AS `playlist_id`,
  pl.`name` AS `playlist_name`,
  t.`id` AS `track_id`,
  t.`title` AS `track_title`,
  t.`name` AS `track_name`,
  t.`art` AS `track_art`,
  t.`likes` AS `track_likes`,
  t.`downloads` AS `track_downloads`,
  t.`views` AS `track_plays`
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN playlists AS pl
  ON i.idu = pl.by
INNER JOIN playlistsentries AS ple
  ON pl.id = ple.playlists
INNER JOIN tracks AS t
  ON ple.track = t.id
ORDER BY `user_id` ASC, `playlist_id` ASC, `track_id` ASC
```

Note that I am aliasing fields to remove ambiguity, so we clearly now whether we are working with user, playlist, or track-level fields.

When fetching the result set, you are iterating over one track at a time. We have ordered the result set such that all users, playlists and tracks are ordered (grouped) together such that you can look for changes in the current row values to determine if you need to build new higher level data containers for users and playlists.

Example code to implement the writing of the data structure you desired and encoding to JSON is shown below:

```
// variable in which to store your results to be serialize
$result_array = array();
// some index and temp variables we will use to build the data structure
$current_user_id = 0;
$user_idx = -1;
$current_playlist_id = 0;
$playlist_idx = -1;
// Your database fetch logic here.
// I have not shown where actual query would be made.
// The query would obviously need to succeed before getting to this code.
// Note that you REALLY should be considering mysqli or PDO here
// instead of deprecated mysql extension.
while($row = /* your DB line fetch here - Consider using mysqli or PDO */) {
    // is this a new user?
    $user_id = (integer)$row['user_id'];
    if($user_id !== $current_user_id) {
        // manage our indexes
        $current_user_id = $user_id;
        $user_idx++;
        $playlist_idx = -1;
        // start a new object to store data for this user
        $user_obj = new stdClass();
        // set properties on user from current row
        // name these properties whatever you want for final JSON structure
        $user_obj->idu = $current_user_id;
        $user_obj->username = $row['user_name'];
        $user_obj->first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $user_obj->last_name = $row['last_name'];
        $user_obj->country = $row['user_country'];
        $user_obj->image = $row['user_image'];
        $user_obj->cover = $row['user_cover'];
        $user_obj->description = $row['user_description'];
        $user_obj->playlists = array();
        // set object in overall result array
        $result_array[$user_idx] = $user_obj;
     }

     // does this playlist already exist for this user?
     $playlist_id = (int)$row['playlist_id'];
     if($playlist_idx === -1 || $playlist_id !== $current_playlist_id ) {
         // manage our indexes
         $current_playlist_id = $playlist_id;
         $playlist_idx++;
         // start a new object to store data for this user
         $playlist_obj = new stdClass();
         // set properties on playlist from current row
         // name these properties whatever you want for final JSON structure
         $playlist_obj->id = $current_playlist_id;
         $playlist_obj->name = $row['playlist_name'];
         $playlist_obj->by = $current_user_id;
         $playlist_obj->tracks = array();
         // set object in overall result array
         $result_array[$user_idx]->playlists[$playlist_idx] = $playlist_obj;
      }

      // create track object
      // we do this for every row
      $track_obj = new stdClass();
      $track_obj->id = $row['track_id'];
      $track_obj->title = $row['track_title'];
      $track_obj->name = $row['track_name'];
      $track_obj->art = $row['track_art'];
      $track_obj->likes = $row['track_likes'];
      $track_obj->downloads = $row['track_downloads'];
      $track_obj->plays = $row['track_plays'];
      $track_obj->uid = $current_user_id;

      // set track object in result set
      $result_array[$user_idx]->playlists[$playlist_idx]->tracks[] = $track_obj;
}
// serialize to JSON
$result_json = json_encode($result_array);
```

Note: I wasn't quite sure what the differences, if any between the various user id values that you showed for each nesting level.  The code above may need to be modified if for example the user id for the track and/or playlist represents a different user than the current user.  If this is the case, you would need to add these fields into the query and add the properties to the objects.

Comment: thanks for your input... its beyond my skill level for me to take it all in so quick... but i will try to grasp it some later tonight... from what i could understand, it does seem like the right way to approach this

Comment: yes, user ID is for each user, they get their own id (notice the users table),